# What would happen if I rm -rf on a mounted gcsfuse directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

Let's say I have a mounted bucket at path `~/path/to/mount/point` on my local machine. What would happen if I `rm -rf ~/path/to/mount/point`. Only the mount point directory would be deleted or also all its content (hence all the bucket content)?

I don't want to try this command on the bucket I am currently working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-rf is to remove data recursively. So it removes all the directory content as well. rm -rf on gcsfuse mounted directory is similar to performing rm-rf on any other directory.